# Making a Toothbrush Bristle in Blender

Tags: modeling, modifiers, physics

I am taking the inspiration for this mini-project from a contest on freelancer.com. The goal is to create ONE toothbrush bristle in Blender that behaves (simulates) like a real bristle. *No particles or hair simulation allowed*. You can find the original instructions link [here.](https://www.freelancer.de/contest/Tootbrush-bristle-to-behave-physically-correct-in-Blender-D-1847289).

Here is my pitiful result:
https://media.blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/a/1/1/a1122ab88d1a9541e14df6a5f6ab330cf8dc21c2.mp4

I used a lattice to create a soft body simulation on a cylinder and added weights to the cylinder to simulate some kind of stiffness.

[image]

The sphere (tooth) passed straight through the soft body and I can't add any collision modifier to the lattice. I guess I am onto something here, but I feel like I am missing some important steps in my thought process.

How would you go about building something like this? Do you have any ideas? Why is the soft body not colliding with the sphere?

Thank you very much for any input!

Here is the file:
https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/5fYazp97zNu8RXDgYL9wirOqvbh.blend